# 2 Ways of calling free - is there a difference?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory, free

Is there a difference between those two variants of calling `free` after allocating memory on the heap:

```
// variant 1
int* p1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
free(p1);

//variant 2
int* p2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
free(*p2);
*p2 = NULL;
```

Comment: only the pointer p1 or p2 is allocated and thus can be freed. Dereferencing the pointer with *p2 only gets you an instance within the allocated block.

Comment: You will only see the second variant when **the address** of `p2` is passed to a function (e.g. `some_func (int **p) {...}` and you call `some_func (&p2)`) Then within `some_func`, it would be valid to `free(*p);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

Variant 2 is invalid. `free` expects a pointer previously returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. `*p2` is the first `int` **in the allocated space**, though. As `man free` says, undefined behavior occurs therefore (quotation adjusted for this specific case):

> `free()` function frees the memory space pointed to by [`p1`], which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`. Otherwise, [...] undefined behavior occurs.

---

Notes:

- [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `free(*p2)` is invalid.

`free` frees the memory at the address it's given. Consider: what does `p1` evaluate to? Its value is the pointer that `malloc` returned - so `p1` evaluates to the pointer to the memory that `malloc` allocated.

What does `*p2` evaluate to? Its value is the integer that is stored at the address of `p2`. This can be anything and it is very unlikely it'll be a valid pointer. Thus `free` will attempt to free an invalid memory address and you'll get a segfault if you're lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a difference. The first way, called on a pointer pointing to memory allocated by `malloc` is right. The second, calling a dereference of such a pointer, attempts to free some arbitrary memory address (with the value held in the **value** that pointer is pointing to), and is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
free(p1);
```

This is valid as you allocate memory to `p1` and then `free`, thus no problem.

```
free(*p2);
```

It is unlikely to be valid as `*p2` may or may not be a valid pointer (which need to have an allocated memoty ).

**using free() on a pointer which is not allcocated memory using malloc or similar will cause error**.